# How to pass argument with spaces to a shell script function?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I'm trying to pass multiple argument to a function, but one of them is consist of two words and I want shell function to deal with it as one arg:

```
args=("$@")
function(){
 echo ${args[0]}
 echo ${args[1]}
 echo ${args[2]}
}
```

when I call this command `sh shell hi hello guys bye`

I get this

```
hi

hello

guys
```

But what I really want is:

```
hi 
hello guys
bye
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `function` as a name of a function. It's a keyword in `ksh`, and some bourne-shell like `bash`, `zsh`, `dash`.

Comment: @Gnouc. Not in `dash`. In `yash` yes. Though `zsh` also accepts `ksh`'s function definition syntax, `function() echo x; function` will work in `zsh`. So the only shells where that is a problem are `ksh`, `bash` and `yash`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, I retry and it works in `zsh`, but `dash` doesn't.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should just quote the second argument.

```
myfunc(){
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
        echo "$3"
}

myfunc hi "hello guys" bye
```

Answer (score 17):

It is the same as calling anything (a shell script, a C program, a python program, …) from a shell

If calling from any Unix shell, and the parameter has spaces, then you need to quote it.

```
sh my-shell-script hi "hello guys" bye
```

You can also use single quotes, these are more powerful. They stop the shell from interpreting anything (`$`, `!`, `\`, `*`, `"`,  etc, except `'`)

```
sh my-shell-script hi 'hello guys' bye
```

You should also quote every variable used within the function/script.

Note that in your example the arguments are falling apart before they get to the function (as they are passed to the script).

```
#!/bin/sh
my_procedure{
   echo "$1"
   echo "$2"
   echo "$3"
}
my_procedure("$@")
```

There is no way to do it automatically, in the script, as there is no way for the script to know which spaces are which (which words are together).

Comment: And if the parameter has " in it? We need to encode it?

Comment: Escape it. `\"`

Comment: What if 'hello guys' is stored in a variable?

Comment: @Jacob "You should also quote every variable used within the function/script." (extracted from answer).

Comment: @Sam I don't grok your comment. What are you wondering?

Comment: Double quotes don't help to escape `*` on macOS Monterey:
myuser@my-MacBook ~ % sh dblookup.sh "select * from some_table;" 
... echo $1 ...
select Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Parallels Pictures Public from some_table;

Comment: @AliaksandrAdzinets That is nothing to do with MacOS. I will not answer here as it is not the place. You should ask another question. However, your shell did not expand the `*`. `sh` did.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for your reply. My example has worked after changing `echo $1` to `echo "$1"`.