# shell arguments with spaced passed as files instead of commands

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have read this [Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151807/how-to-pass-argument-with-spaces-to-a-shell-script-function), but it seems to always think the parameter as file.

I want to transform the command `diff <(ls old) <(ls new)` from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229447/how-do-i-diff-the-output-of-two-commands) to one function which receive two arguments, although it is somewhat redundant.

I tried this which is just arg replace:

```bash
d2c(){
        diff <($1) <($2)
}
```

then run `d2c "objdump -d foo1" "objdump -d foo2"` show `d2c:1: no such file or directory: objdump -d foo1`

with [*fifo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800202/diff-output-from-two-programs-without-temporary-files) , above problem still be there.

Q: How can I pass arg like '"objdump -d foo1"', then let it run as command?

Comment: Are you using zsh?

Comment: For the use case presented here, I think you might just want to use `eval`: `d2c () { diff <(eval "$1") <(eval "$2"); }`, but if you're on zsh, you can also try `d2c () diff <(${(z)1}) <(${(z)2})`

Comment: @muru, you'd also need a `Q` (to remove quotes) and `@` within quotes to preserve empty elements in addition to that `z` tokenisation flag, but that would mean one could only run simple commands so would have no advantage over `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for offering so many solutions. I use bash (sorry for not clarifying this when posting.) And `eval "$1"` works for me.

Comment: The error message you provided seems to suggest that word splitting is not done with the unquoted `$1`, but that's not the default in bash, where it is in zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want those `$1` and `$2` to be interpreted as shell code as opposed to being the name of a command to execute, so you'd need:

```
d2c() {
  diff <(eval " $1") <(eval " $2")
}
```

(note the leading space to avoid problems with commands whose name starts with `-`).

You'll also want to make sure you use single quotes and not double quotes when passing those codes to `d2c` to remove the risk of introducing command injection vulnerabilities.

```
d2c 'echo "$var1"' 'echo "$var2"; echo "$var3"'
```

**Not**

```
d2c "echo $var1" "echo $var2; echo $var3"
```

For instance.